# setting white font color for dark background and V.S. in php

Tags: php, javascript, css

while changing to dark background , I need to set the font color to white and exactly in opposite , when the background is bright so the font color should be black

i don't the range to divide the dark and light colors in php

my color codes are in hex format #ffffff

Comment: I think this is a css, or javascript question, not php?

Comment: are you trying to have alternate rows in a table? One row white, the next row black, and so on?

Comment: nah , just read the question , its about guessing the white or black font color according to dark or light background ,, I mean how to devide hex color codes to dark and light colors so that we can set font colors such as black and white to them.

Comment: @Mac.  Could you provide more context?  Where are the background colors coming from?  Are they dynamically generated on different pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this method working for my issue.
http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/9769.htm

Answer (score 2):

You could take the three parts of your color (red, green and blue) and build the sum. The minimum value you will get is 0 and the maximum value is 765.
You could say that values below 380 are dark and values above are bright and set the text color accordingly.

Or you take the [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) definition and say that value := max(red, green, blue) and values above 128 are bright and values below are dark

Answer (score -1):

There is no "real definition" of a dark background. You could switch from one type to the other if the contrast (eg. the sum of the R, G and B differences) is not high enough.